# Update another table when SSIS data flow finishes

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a simple package where I pull down every table from a remote source DB into my local server DB.
Every data flow task is simple source to destination.
The problem I have is occasionally the download will stop and I won't get all the tables, or sometimes tables won't fully pull down all data.

All I want to do is have a table with all table names that I need to pull down.

After each table in my data flow completes I need to update a flag in my new table of table names so that there is a 1 for every table that fully downloads from the source to the destination.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that there are many tables so having one per data flow task doesn't really work, I have them separated out in data flow tasks called "tables A-F", "tables G-L"...and within those data flow tasks there are 10 - 15 tables each.  Now if I could add a SQL task or transform step after each destination I would be fine, but the only thing you can do coming from a destination is create an error output.   I know I can add a SQL task after each data flow task saying that every table in this step completed but would like some way to tell that each table itself completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to add an `Execute SQL Task` after each `Data Flow Task` that updates the table containing a `LastOperationDate` which will have the last execution time.

```
UPDATE AuditTable
SET  LastExecutionDate=GETDATE()
WHERE TableName LIKE @param
```

The @param is the name of the table in the data destination of the concerned data flow.